# npm install saitek -g keeps installing wrong dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install an sdk from https://github.com/niftylettuce/flightgear-saitek-pro-flight-switch-panel-hid-controller

the package.json looks as follows:

```
{
  "name": "saitek",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": "Nick Baugh <niftylettuce@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bin": {
    "saitek": "./app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^0.4.0",
    "node-hid": "^0.5.4",
    "underscore": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

It clearly states it needs node-hid@0.5.4

When I check in my terminal (npm show node-hid version), it returns 0.7.3

As soon as I give the command:

> npm install saitek -g

It starts with:

> > node-hid@0.3.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/saitek/node_modules/node-hid

Clearly not the version I want. Especially as it gives all kinds of errors, which breaks the install.

I am on a MacBook Pro with Sierra as operating system.

Comment: -g means global.. so it’s been awhile since i used npm but you might need to specify to use the global cache if that’s where you installed it

Comment: Can I specify this in the command line, or is it a rule that should be added to the package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of saitek on GitHub is more up-to-date; it has the `node-hid` dependency 0.5. If you install a package, `npm` will install the declared dependencies for that package. The last version of `saitek` released on npm is 4 years old and has an older node-hid dependency:

```
npm view saitek dependencies
{ ... 'node-hid': '^0.3.1' ...
```

It's up to the owner of the `saitek` package to publish a new version. You might try contacting them or getting in touch with npm support: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/disputes

In the meantime you can install the package directly from GitHub since it has an updated `package.json`:

```
npm install -g https://github.com/niftylettuce/flightgear-saitek-pro-flight-switch-panel-hid-controller
```

This doesn't seem to work with node 10, but it does work with node 9 and 6 at least.

It's possible that `npm install -g saitek` will work with an even older version of node. It didn't work for 6 for me though.

Comment: The interesting thing is that I am already using the latest version from github. If you look again at my first post, you'll see the ^0.5.4 in the package.json. So how come it still takes 0.3.2?

Comment: @RobertvanderSpek how are you using the latest version from GitHub? Did you clone it?

Comment: I downloaded it as a zip.

Comment: Where are you running `npm install`?

Comment: In the folder containing the app.js and package.json files.

Comment: What is the exact command you are running when you're in that folder?

Comment: npm install saitek -g

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180072/discussion-between-robert-van-der-spek-and-explosion-pills).

Comment: That still installs from the registry. If you've downloaded the repo and want to install it from source, use `npm link`.